# A bounded set in euclidean space with nonempty interior has a max ball radius

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to answer the following question. Suppose $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded and has nonempty interior. Show that there is an $r \in (0, ∞)$ such that $S$ contains some ball $B_r(x)$ of radius $r$, but it contains no ball $B_R(x)$ of
radius strictly greater than $r$.

This is what I'm trying. Let $r = \text{sup }\{t \mid B_t(x) \subseteq S \text{ for some } x \in \mathbb{R}^n \}$. Since $S$ is bounded and has nonempty interior, $r \in (0, ∞)$. I need to show that $r$ is in fact a maximum.

I am not sure whhere to go next. My instinct is to take an increasing sequence $(r_m)$ that converges to $r$ with the corresponding points $(x_m)$ such that $B_{r_m}(x_m) \subseteq S$, and produce some ball of radius $r$ contained in $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will talk about open balls. Let for every $r>0$ $B_r$ be the set of centers of balls of radius $r$ inside $S$. Since $S$ is bounded, $B_r$ is empty for every $r>R$ for some $R$. Since $S$ has non-empty interior, $B_r$ is not empty for some $r$. Let $u$ be the supremum of all $r$ such that $S_r$ is not empty (clearly $u\le R$). Then $S$ cannot contain balls of radius $>u$. But for every big enough $n\gg 1$ it contains a ball of radius $>u-1/n$ with center $x_n$. The sequence $x_n, n\ge 1$ is bounded, so it has a subsequence that has a limit $x$. Then for every sufficiently large $m>0$ there exists a ball $B(x,u-1/m)$ inside $S$. Then the whole ball $B(x,u)$ is inside $S$, so $B_u$ is not empty. So $u$ is the maximal ball radius in $S$. $\Box$

Comment: I'm not sure I follow: Then for every sufficiently large m>0 there exists a ball B(x,u−1/m) inside S. Then the whole ball B(x,u) is inside S, so Bu is not empty.

Comment: Which statement is not clear?

Comment: Both of those statements. That for every sufficiently large m>0 there exists a ball B(x,u−1/m) inside S, and that this impies the whole ball B(x,u) is inside S

Comment: About the first statement. For every small $\epsilon>0$ there exists $x_m$ which is $\epsilon/2$-close to $x$ and such that the ball $B=B(x_m,u-\epsilon/2$-ball is inside $S$. Then, $x$ is inside $B$ and, moreover, the whole ball $B(x,u-\epsilon)$ is inside $B\subseteq S$, by the triangle inequality. About the second statement. Since $B(x,u-\epsilon)\subseteq S$ for every arbitrary small $\epsilon$, $B(x,u)=\cup_{\epsilon} B(x, u-\epsilon)$ is inside $S$, because we consider open balls.

Comment: Thank you. Interestingly, it doesn't hold for closed balls I believe.

Comment: For closed balls consider the open interval $(0,1)$. It is bounded and has interior, but it does not have biggest $r$ such that $\overline{B(x,r)}$ is inside $(0,1)$.